# SVM parameters clarification

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, svm, optimization

James et al. in [An introduction to the statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) (p. 351) claim that the solution to the support vector classifier problem

[image]

involves only the *inner products* of the observations. They stated that linear support vector classifier can be represented as

[image]

where there are $n$ parameters $\alpha$. According to my understanding, $\beta$s are hyperplane parameters and $\alpha$s are coefficients of support vectors.

**My questions:** How are $\alpha$s related to the $\beta$s?

Any pointers are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primal ($\vec{\beta}$) and dual ($\vec{\alpha}$) parameters are related via $\vec{\beta} = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\vec{x}_i$, in other words, the hyperplane parameters can be written as a linear combination of the support vectors (some $\alpha_i$ will hopefully be zero).  This can be seen by comparing the output of the model expressed in primal form $f(\vec{x}) = \beta_0 + <\vec{\beta},\vec{x}>$ with that expressed in dual form, as given in the question.  HTH.